# iOS8 Camera Permission Prompt shown - But Camera not used

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-camera

I recently updated to iOS8. On my Apps there is now a camera permission dialog.
I do not have any camera related code in my App. (I had but I removed almost everything of it)

Frameworks I use

```
QuartzCore
AssetLibrary
SystemConfiguration
MessageUI
AdSupport
AudioToolbox
StoreKit
UiKit
Foundation
CoreGraphics
GLKit
OpenGLES
IOKit
CoreFoundation
CoreServices
OpenGL
CoreMotion
StoreKit
(libGoogleAdMobAds)
```

How can I disable this prompt?
Any hint what could causes this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was a caching problem. After I removed all camera related code there was still a privacy-camera entry in the settings page.
Then I changed the die package id and I rebuilt everything. Now there was no camera permission dialog and the camera privacy setting was gone.